# Python script throws 502.2 but no error shown in description

Tags: python, cgi

All my python scripts run when called and return results. In this case, however, I am calling a second script from the first by clicking on a link in the first and passing a parameter to the second. In the past on a different server it worked flawlessly. After a hiatus the project is being resurrected. But now the second script throws a 502.2 but dies not show any actual error condition or state, only a good amount of script. See below. If I comment out the line immediately following the screen dump and rerun the script runs until farther down. This time it stops midway through a loop that reads data from a Splunk search. It returns 3 1/2 records before stopping. I can find nothing in event logs and can't see any problem with the script code itself. Here is the screen dump. It doesn't seem to be actually timing out but I can't be sure. It seems to be running fine and then just craps out for no reason.

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. 
The headers it did return are "Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br /> Content-Type:text\html <html> <head> <title>Mid-Tier Stats</title> <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/table.css' /> <style> table { font: 0.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse:collapse; background:#e8eef7; color:#000; } #itsthetable { height:280px; overflow:auto; background:#c6dbff; padding-bottom:3px; width: 635px; } #itsthetableheader { overflow:auto; background:#c6dbff; padding-bottom:3px; width: 635px; } caption { height:102px; font-size:000000.1em; color:#c6dbff; background:#c6dbff; } caption:hover{ font-size:000000.1em; color:#c6dbff; background:transparent; } th {font-weight:300;} tr th, tr td {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;} table a, table a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#666;} table a:visited {color:#999;} tbody tr th { width:80px; vertical-align:top; padding-left: 50px; background:transparent; } tbody tr td { height:1.7em; vertical-align:top; padding-left:10px; background:transparent; } thead { background:#fff;} tr th + td + td + td + td { width:60px; padding-left:20px; font-size:0.9em; background:transparent; } tr.odd { background: #FFFFFF; } tfoot th, tfoot td { height:105px; font-weight:bold; height:2.0em; padding-left:10px; vertical-align: top; } tfoot th{ height:102px; background:#c6dbff; } tfoot td {height:102px; background:#c6dbff; }</style> </head> <body bgcolor='lightSteelBlue' ><h3> <div id='content'> <img src='images\john2srv.PNG' width=75 height=85 align='middle' />Server Farm #2 Johnstown </h3> <table><tr bgcolor='lightSteelBlue'> ".

```
OK, Here


The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are 
"Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Server Farm #2 Johnstown <br />
 Content-Type:text\html <html>
<head>
<title>Mid-Tier Stats</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/table.css' />
<style> table {
 font: 0.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 background:#e8eef7;
 color:#000;
 }
 #itsthetable {
 height:280px;
 overflow:auto;
 background:#c6dbff;
 padding-bottom:3px;
 width: 635px;
 }
 #itsthetableheader {
 overflow:auto;
 background:#c6dbff;
 padding-bottom:3px;
 width: 635px;
 }
 caption {
 height:102px;
 font-size:000000.1em;
 color:#c6dbff;
 background:#c6dbff;
 }
 caption:hover{
 font-size:000000.1em;
 color:#c6dbff;
 background:transparent;
 }
 th {
font-weight:300;
}
 tr th, tr td {
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
 table a, table a:link {
text-decoration:none;
 color:#666;
}
 table a:visited {
color:#999;
}
 tbody tr th {
 width:80px;
 vertical-align:top;
 padding-left: 50px;
 background:transparent;
 }
 tbody tr td {
 height:1.7em;
 vertical-align:top;
 padding-left:10px;
 background:transparent;
 }
 thead {
 background:#fff;
}
 tr th + td + td + td + td {
 width:60px;
 padding-left:20px;
 font-size:0.9em;
 background:transparent;
 }
 tr.odd {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 }
 tfoot th, tfoot td {
 height:105px;
 font-weight:bold;
 height:2.0em;
 padding-left:10px;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
 tfoot th{
 height:102px;
 background:#c6dbff;
 }
 tfoot td {
height:102px;
 background:#c6dbff;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor='lightSteelBlue' ><h3>
<div id='content'>
<img src='images\john2srv.PNG' width=75 height=85 align='middle' />Server Farm #2 Johnstown </h3>
<table><tr bgcolor='lightSteelBlue'> ".
```

Comment: Arggh, my eyes! Paste your code normally, and use the `{ }` tool to mark it as code.

Comment: That's the 502.2 message. I want you to see what I see.

Comment: OK, I formatted all of the code shown on the screen message. It's still just css and HTML and it still just stops partway into the script with no rhyme or reason.